# Use of the :not selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website with different sections. I have jQuery to slide between these sections.
But now I have a link in a section which points to another section.

**HTML**:

```
    <div class="section" id="one">
        <div class="row">
            <p>This is some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <a href="#" onclick="scrollOrderNow()"><img src="button"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="tow">
        <div class="row">
            <p>This is some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <a href="#" onclick="scrollOrderNow()"><img src="button"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="ordernow">
        <div class="row">
            <p>This is some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <a href="#" onclick="scrollOrderNow()"><img src="button"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="four">
        <div class="row">
            <p>This is some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <a href="#" onclick="scrollOrderNow()"><img src="button"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// onclick on an object with class "section" scroll to this object
$('div.section').click(function() {
    $.scrollTo($(this), 800);
});

function scrollOrderNow(){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#ordernow").offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

The problem is that if I click on the link `scrollOrderNow()` the page slides to the order page and than back to the section because the link is in that section.

Could you please help me figure this out?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single click handler and determine what to do based on which element was clicked inside the section. For this, it's best to distinguish the clickable element by giving it a class:

```
<div class="section" id="four">
  <div class="row">
      <p>This is some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <a href="#"><img src="button" class="scroll-to-order"/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The the click handler code:

```
$('div.section').on('click', function(evt) {
    var $target = $(evt.target);

    if ($target.is('.scroll-to-order')) {
        // the image itself was clicked, so scroll to ordernow
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#ordernow").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        // something else inside the section was clicked, scroll to section
        $.scrollTo($(this), 800);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put `return false` to your `scrollOrderNow()` function.

```
function scrollOrderNow(){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#ordernow").offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
}
```

This way, your links will not react and the hash will not be appended to the URL, leaving the page where it is.

Comment: It's much better to use the `event.preventDefault()` method, than to simply return false. Returning false has other implications that you didn't mention, namely that it also prevents event bubbling.

Comment: @BenM you're probably right - I never actually needed to bubble something up when trying to prevent an event though, so that's probably why it didn't come to my mind :)

Comment: I tried to add the event.preventDefault() and return false; but they both do not work. I have put up a test for you to see: http://mijnfuur.nl/test/ could you please look for me once more?

Comment: @Blacktoko well, it worked for me on Chrome - what browser have you tried? did you clear your cache?